# Obtain string inside curl bracket in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Suppose I have a string like

```
{"", "b", "c"}, // we are here
```

I would like to extract the `{"", "b", "c"}` and/or `"", "b", "c"` part of it. Is there any simple prescription for it?

Comment: Is this a set of strings or are the brackets actually part of the string (e.g., `'{"", "b", "b"}'`)?

Comment: part of string, sorry for confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex - `re.search`:

```
import re

s = '{"", "b", "c"}, // we are here'
m = re.search(r'{.*}', s)
print(m.group(0))
#'{"", "b", "c"}'
```

`{.*}` matches every thing within the curly braces and the braces.